# Slow Lasso Performance Using sklearn

Tags: python, lasso, model-evaluation, elastic-net

I am trying to use scikit-learn's `LassoCV` and/or `ElasticNetCV` functions to model a dataset with a large (>800) number of predictors.

I'm using the latest version of sklearn on a Retina MacBook Pro (2013), and finding that the performance is relatively quick, especially if I do parallelization on the cross-validations.

However, I would prefer to use our compute cluster that has 24 cores (AMD), as I could do more parallel computations and leave it running without making my laptop useless (I am running this model thousands of times on different data).

The data in the model is `X.shape = (4053, 849)`, and `y.shape = (4053,)`.

The performance for just 10 cross-validations of a single model is:

Macbook Pro: `1.5 sec` 
Compute Cluster: `144 sec`

What could account for this massive difference in performance?  The laptop is using Apple's accelerate linear algebra libraries, while the cluster uses OpenBLAS, so I expect a small difference, but not the orders of magnitude difference I'm getting here.  The code is identical, as is the data.

Note, I also ran a test using fake data on both LassoCV and ElasticNetCV.  Strangely, the performance was about 2-3x slower on the compute cluster, but that's significantly better than with the real data set.  The fake data set was actually significantly larger `(5000,20000)`, so it's not a scaling issue.  Is it possible that by importing data from Matlab using the h5py module (the real data), I'm storing the data in arrays that are not as efficient in some way?